# what is the final concentration of the mixture

Tags: acid-base, solutions

In a bizarre twist of chemical fate, an accident results in you results in you mixing 2L of a 3.00M solution of NaCl with 4L of a 1.50M solution of NaCl. what is the final concentration of the mixture?

Comment: I'm not going to answer it for you but think of it this way: find out the amount (not to be confused with concentration) of salt in each mixture, and then work out the volume of the final mixture. Paying attention to the units of your quantities can help with conversions, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I can't post the answer all you have to do is calculate number of moles by the formula $$ M_1*V_1+ M_2*V_2 $$ and divide this by total volume which in this case would be $$ V_1 + V_2 $$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).